# Fetch screenshots from s3 via EC2

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have the following requirement
- There is an html file containing the test report which has screenshots of all the test steps. When a user opens the html report from his machine he should be able to view the screenshots. Hence the screenshots need to be stored at a central location

Current implementation
1) The screenshots are being created on an EC2 instance and are then being uploaded to s3. The s3 bucket has public access
2) The html report has the absolute S3 path of the screenshot image. Hence the user can view the screenshots.

Challenge
1) We need to now implement this solution behind a corporate firewall where public access cannot be granted to the s3 bucket
2) The EC2 can access the S3 via an IAM role.
3) Hence how do we ensure that the screenshots in the report are accessible to the users

Suggested solution
1) Implement a javascript within the html which at runtime fetches the screenshots. But not sure on the feasibility of the same.

Note: A network drive is not a viable option due to slow read/write speeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) an option? In particular the signed URLs and cookies.  It's designed to serve private content with CloudFront.

Comment: Definitely an option but need to check with my IT Infra team. Thanks